# Multiple inputs with names that represent a product id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing an order system in **Laravel** and I encountered a problem when trying to process the products of the order.

The page looks like this:

[image]

Each Product entry represents an item in a table called Products that has id,name and price as columns.

When I'm sending the form , each QTY input has as name the product's id(for Cabbage is 1 , for Water is 3, for Bread is 4 ).
Something like this(for cabbage):

```
<input style="width:70px;margin-bottom:9px;" class="qty form-control input-lg" required="required" name="1" type="number" value="">
```

One of the problems is that those aren't the single inputs on the page and I can't really identify them from the rest.

When the form is sent I would want to take those values , search in the db , get the name of each product based on id and make a simple list like:

```
Cabbage - 2 qty
Water - 1 qty
Bread - 3 qty
```

What I'm asking is what would be the best way to get the list above as the products will be dynamic(removed , added , modified , etc).

Initially I thought of something like:

```
//all inputs with name products[] and as value the product id

$items = Input::get('products');

foreach($items as $item){
    $prodid = Product::find($item);
    echo $prodid['name'];
}
```

But doing so I wouldn't know the qty value , I'm pretty much stuck.
I appreciate any ideas that would help me achieve what I explained.

Thank you!

Comment: first save quantity value in database.  then you can show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sent the quantities also as an array, so name you qte inputs like `quantities[]`, then get them by index in the controller :

```
$product_ids = Input::get('products'); //input name products[]
$quantities  = Input::get('quantities'); //input name quantities[]

foreach($product_ids as $index=>$product_id){
    $product  = Product::find($product_id);
    $quantity = $quantities[$index];

    echo $product['name'].' : '.$quantity;
}
```